# проблема hasMany в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

есть вот такой запрос

```
            $top_cats = ModArendaTree::find()->with('adscount')->where(['active' => 1])->andWhere(['parent_id' => 0])->orderBy(['popular' => SORT_DESC, 'sort' => SORT_DESC])->all();
```

определил связь в модели

```
public function getAdscount(){
    return $this->hasMany(CatsForAds2::className(),['ad_id'=>'id'])->count();
}
```

однако выводит ошибку будто такой связи нет

```
app\modules\Tree\models\ModArendaTree has no relation named "adscount".

но есть в связи убираю "->count()" то все отлично работает... Почему так?
```

Answer (score 1):

При построении запроса, метод `->with('adscount')` ищет в `ModArendaTree` метод `getAdscount()` который возвращает экземпляр класса `ActiveQuery`.

Когда вы добавляете `->count()`, метод будет пытаться вернуть уже число а не экземпляр класса, по этому строитель запроса его просто не находит.

Comment: а что мне делать если мне не нужна вся таблица а всего лишь количество найденных записей?

Comment: Связь это не результат запроса, это грубо говоря описание `join` (хотя в данном случае будет два запроса). Вот и используйте `->count()` не в связи а в результатах.